# Use round or floor depending the number after the comma

Tags: php, rounding, floor

What would be the solution to have:

`7.1` => `7`

`7.5` => `7`

`7.8` => `8`

So I need to `round` number or `floor` depending on the number after the comma.

How to do that?

Thanks.

Comment: What coma? Where?  Or comma?  Still, where?

Comment: Coma, point, ... Tbnk!!

Comment: I don't understand the question. It seems like you're actually asking about `floor` or `ceil`. `round` always returns the closest integer, which can be higher or lower depending on the fraction.

Comment: See the accepted answer then you will understand the question.

Comment: Which way do you want `7.51` to round?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to use the constant, `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, to have the `round` function round down when it is half way.

```
echo round(7.1, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "\n";
echo round(7.5, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "\n"; 
echo round(7.8, 0, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "\n";
```

Output:

```
7
7
8
```

From the [manual](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php):

> Round val down to precision decimal places towards zero, when it is half way there. Making 1.5 into 1 and -1.5 into -1.

PHP Demo: https://eval.in/427706

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this is to split the value at the decimal (or comma?  your example is using decimals) and test the trailing number to see whether you want to use floor or ceiling.

```
$test = 7.6
$arrayTest = explode(".",$test);
if(isset($arrayTest[1]) && $arrayTest[1] > 5) {
   //do something
} else {
   //do something else
}
```

Comment: Answer proportional to your rank.

Comment: Try your answer with `7.123`.

Comment: @Barmar - the comparison I gave ( > 5) was only an example based on the OP's example.  When I posted my answer, I didn;t realize that the OP was actually trying to round down or up.  OP stated he wanted to do floor or ceiling based on the number after the decimal / comma

Comment: My general point is that any numeric comparison of the number after the decimal doesn't take the number of digits into account.

Comment: I get that... but that's not what the OP asked for.

Comment: It seems like we have a different interpretation of what he asked for.